# Some watir-webdriver functionality is missing in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, watir

```
b.driver.manage.window.resize_to(1000, 1000)
```

That line above doesn't work with chrome on my mac. I am running watir-webdriver 0.6.1 and selenium-webdriver 2.22.2.

I get the following error:

```
1.9.3-p125 :003 > b.driver.manage.window.resize_to(1000, 1000)
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unknown error, status=405: ["GET", "HEAD", "DELETE"]
```

I haven't installed ChromeDriver. Just running directly with the help of the above 2 gems. Any help would be much appreciated. For some reason, the latest watir-webdriver doesn't require safari-driver or chrome-driver. In fact, installing Chromedriver and putting it in the PATH in this case, breaks the functionality with chrome. I cannot get chrome up and running at all with ChromeDriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
browser.window.resize_to(x, y)
browser.window.move_to(x, y)
```

I was able to get this to work on the most current version of chrome. Bypass using driver.manage functions.

Comment: `1.9.3-p125 :011 > b.window.resize_to(20,20)
 => #<struct Selenium::WebDriver::Dimension width=20, height=20> ` this is what i get with safari using the latest watir webdriver... it doesn't seem to work with chrome though for some reason.. heres the error with chrome again: `1.9.3-p125 :022 > b.window.resize_to(300, 400)
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unknown error, status=405: ["GET", "HEAD", "DELETE"]
 from /Users/buzz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@railtwit/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok'`

Comment: safari works fine with your command, not chrome though.. which version of selenium webdriver and watir-webdriver do you use.. do you enable other "require" statements at the head apart from "require watir-webdriver"??

Comment: require 'rubygems'. The irb does this for you but if you running any editor you need to include rubygems. As for chrome I think you are missing the chrome webdriver. Download it and place it in your executable path.

Comment: [Chromedriver](http://watirwebdriver.com/chrome/) <= link should be useful for chrome issues.

Comment: I tried placing ChromeDriver in my path but it conflicts with the latest watir-webdriver for some reason. Any workarounds people?

Comment: I'm finally resorting to rewrite the CSS in my site so I will not need to fullscreen it. It would have been nice if this function worked though...

Comment: @sambehera. Re d/l the new chromedriver and delete the older one in your exe path. New version can be found at: http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list

Comment: thanks for your support! I'll check with the new version of chromedriver.